# ошибка в Route и почему-то не может найти url

Tags: php, laravel, controller, route, blade

```
public function employees()
    {
        $employees = Employees::all();
        return view('director.employees', ['employees'=>$employees]);
    }
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $employees = Employees::find();
        $employees->delete();
        return redirect('/director.employees')->with('status', 'Your Data is Deleted');
    }

}
```

вот blade файл

```
<from action="{{route('delete', $employee->id)}}" method="post">
    @method('DELETE')
    @csrf
      <button type="submit" title="delete" class="btn btn-delete btn-form me-3">
         Delete
      </button>
 </from>
```

и вот rout.php

```
Route::any('/employees', array(EmployeesController::class, 'employees'))->name('employees');
Route::delete('/delete/{id}', array(EmployeesController::class, 'destroy'))->name('delete');
```

Comment: Какой route не может найти или какая именно ошибка? Какая версия laravel?

Comment: laravel 9 (rout delete not found ошибка)

Comment: А если попробовать `route('delete', ['id'=>$employee->id])` ?

Comment: <from action="/delete/{{$employee->id}}" method="POST"> если так написать то работает, точнее показывает, но теперь кнопка delete  вообще  не работает т.е  не удаляет

Comment: Я хз (. Наверное последнее что могу предложить попробовать в консоли выполнить `php artisan route:clear` чтобы очистить кеш для роутов и `php artisan route:list` посмотреть какие пути есть

Answer (score 0):

В контролере нужно подправить с

```
public function employees()
{
    $employees = Employees::all();
    return view('director.employees', ['employees'=>$employees]);
}
public function destroy($id)
{
    $employees = Employees::find();
    $employees->delete();
    return redirect('/director.employees')->with('status', 'Your Data is Deleted');
}
```

на

```
public function employees()
{
    $employees = Employees::all();
    return view('director.employees', ['employees'=>$employees]);
}
public function destroy($id)
{
    $employees = Employees::find($id);
    $employees->delete();
    return redirect('/director.employees')->with('status', 'Your Data is Deleted');
}
```

так же в роутере вместо any лучше использовать match через Callback

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/', function () {
//});
```

так как any принимает любой запрос.
[Документация Laravel route](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing)